# MacOS Catalina, MacPorts fail to install PuTTY - "Error: Port putty not found"

Tags: macos, putty, macports

I'm trying to install PuTTY on my Mac (OS 10.15.6).

- I have installed Xcode.
- I have installed Xcode Command Line Tools.
- I have installed XQuartz.
- I have installed MacPorts.
- I have run `sudo port selfupdate` from terminal successfully.

When I run `sudo port install putty`, I type in my admin password and then I get:
**"Port putty not found?"**

Any help is much appreciated. Most people on the internet seem have issues getting PuTTY installed because they don't have MacPorts installed - I have it installed but it can't seem to find PuTTY.

Comment: "rsync: failed to connect to rsync.macports.org: Operation timed out (60)
rsync error: error in socket IO (code 10) at /AppleInternal/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/rsync/rsync-54.120.1/rsync/clientserver.c(106) [receiver=2.6.9]
Command failed: /usr/bin/rsync -rtzvl --delete-after rsync://rsync.macports.org/macports/release/tarballs/base.tar /opt/local/var/macports/sources/rsync.macports.org/macports/release/tarballs
Exit code: 10"

Comment: I'm starting to think that the corporate VPN + firewall is preventing updates and other things from happening correctly... and I just haven't been getting a lot of the errors displayed, so I wasn't aware.

Answer (score 3):

Run a debugging MacPorts selfupdate to see where your MacPorts database got corrupted or worse not updated at all:

```
/usr/bin/sudo port -d selfupdate
```

within a `Terminal` or an `xterm` with enough lines to be able to scroll back on each unattended event.